# gzserver problem > dont open

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,
I'm using gazebo-1.9.6 and Ros-Hydro and when I try to run gzserver I've got this message error:

`Exception [Master.cc:50] Unable to start server[Address already in use]. There is probably another Gazebo process running.

Exception [Master.cc:50] Unable to start server[Address already in use]. There is probably another Gazebo process running.`

Anyone can help me with that?

Tkss

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6753/gzserver-problem-%3E-dont-open/) by [Joao Luis](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/911/joao-luis/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-08-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

you have a gazebo server running already. If you cannot see it or don't know how to kill it it it's a background process, try restarting the PC.

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2014-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Joao Luis](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/911/joao-luis/) on 2014-08-12**:
Yeah, I've discovered how to kill it, just run ps on the terminal and after that kill (number of gzserver)